# ScrollTo only Once per Session

Tags: jquery

The following code removes the video header from http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/ after the user scrolls the header size:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
 var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

 if(scrollTop > startScroll) {

     $('.header').addClass('header-remove');
     $('.wrap').addClass('wrap-remove');
     $('.inline-menu').addClass('menu-fixed').css('top', adminBar);

     window.scrollTo(0,0);
     startScroll = 22222;
    }

 });
```

The problem is that it **breaks my menu** navigation on **Singles Pages** like http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/impressum/ Menu links do not scroll to the exact point.

How can I **window.scrollTo(0,0);** once the user scrolls the header height **and** at the same time keep the Single Pages menu working.

Comment: Cant understand the problem that yo uare facing. You need to be more clear.

Comment: The menu does not work properly at http://www.keynote-kommunikation.de/impressum/, links do not drive people to the exact point (#TAG) of the page